# How to configure multiple instances on jenkins to run protractor scripts

Tags: jenkins, automation, protractor

I am new to Jenkins with Protractor . In my current project we have to run all our protractor scripts on Jenkins. We have multiple environments(10 instances) to run our scripts . So, my question is how do i configure different environments on Jenkins. Like each time we have to run the script on a different instance . How do i configure all these instances in Jenkins. Right now i am using a multi pipeline project on Jenkins .

Comment: use choice parameter and then use that to start tests

Comment: Hi Sergey - Sorry.  Can you be more clear . I dint not understand where exactly i need to add that parameter.

Comment: Just look it up, it's too much to type

Comment: For example you have environments DEV, QA1, QA2. You can assign DEV label to 1~2 instances, assign QA1 label to some instances.  Then create a Jenkins pipeline includes a job parameter to choose environment, and set the pipeline agent to the choosen environment, `pipeline { agent { label: params.envName }}` then the job will run on corresponding instances